# Open an app within an app

Tags: gui-design, app

I'm designing a job board app for a client, where users can look for jobs and apply for them. The app is not for one specific client but can be duplicated to the brand and style of multiple clients who offer jobs to candidates. There is also a planning functionality in the app, where the user gets to see his calendar (when he works where, set availabilities, accept work offers,...). However, this planning functionality is an app in itself and **my client would like this planning app to keep its branding and have it opened within the job board app as a sort of iframe** (they want to promote the planning app as a powerful platform).

It doesn't seem common to me to open up apps within apps and have 2 brands live next to each other, but the challenge however is to make this happen.

**Is this a correct approach?**

Comment: From what perspective are you asking? It might well be the financially correct approach, because the client is always correct ;-)  It might also be a usable approach, if you (i.e, the design) and the developers (i.e., the implementation) make it clear that the offering and the planning are separate apps and providers - in that case, 2 different brands may be bearable. But there is not enough information in the question to provide a good answer (mobile/web?, volume of offers, relation between job seeker and planning app provider, ...).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your client is under the impression that apps behave like websites. You could explore:

- Does the user need to download both apps? Yuck. Going to guess there are a lot of competing products that don't require that.
- What happens if they don't download the Planning app? What shows up in the iframe, a big error message?
- What happens if they download the Planning app, but it's worthless outside of the parent app, the user doesn't understand why it exists, and deletes it?
- Does the Planning app have no navigation or page furniture of its own? Or will it show up to the end user as double navigation, double menus...
- Does the Planning app need no authentication or account creation?

**Your client needs to work with APIs, not full apps with UIs.**